# function_traits with varidic tempate and va_args

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Some time ago came across the use of something like this:

```
template <typename Return, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(*)(Args......)>{};
```

Where the above is the variadic expansion of Args, followed by a C style varidic.

Recently on another medium I was discussing this and the other party believed it was still valid to do this:

```
template <typename Return, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(*)(Args...,...)>{};
```

They believed the comma was allowed. But in the past I was forced to use ......, but I don't remember why. It absolutely is on stackoverflow, but it was on an unrelated topic and I couldn't find it again. I do remember something about a MSVC bug which might have forced me to omit the comma.

The question:

1. Are both forms of the varidic expansion valid in that context, if not why?; or
2. Does anybody know where the discussion I remember reading is?; in which case closing the topic then linking it here will help others find the answer. I was no longer able to find it so I assume others will have the same issue.

Comment: How would you know where to split between both forms? And why would you use both anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are both forms of the varidic expansion valid in that context, if not why?

Both forms are indeed valid. The relevant part of grammar production is at [[dcl.fct]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#3)

> ```
> parameter-declaration-clause:
>     parameter-declaration-listopt ...opt
>     parameter-declaration-list , ...
> ```

Either way, `parameter-declaration-list` can be followed to a production that forms a template parameter pack expansion (that's where the second set of would `...` come from).

Comment: Thankyou!
Do you happen to remember any bug with MSVC that only enabled the ...... version?

Comment: @David - I'm afraid I can't help on that front. Haven't used MSVC in a while.